# How can I send email to multiple recipients from SQL Server database in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email

I want to send email to multiple recipients. I retrieve the email addresses of multiple users from a SQL Server database, like this:

```
var students = (from u in db.Users
                where u.projectGroup == id
                select u.userEmail).ToArray();
```

This will return multiple email addresses like: `user1@gmail.com user2@gmail.com`
and I try to send to multiple users like this

```
for (int h = 0; h < students.Length; h++)
{
    try
    {
        var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        var message = new MailMessage();
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(students[h])); 
        message.Subject = "I'm interested in your project";
        message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
            return RedirectToAction("Sent");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //MessageBox("Your Email address is not valid");
        //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Your Email address is not valid');", true);
    }
}
```

but this did not work, it sends an email to first user but another user did not receive the email.

How can I split each email in a one row to send an email to multiple recipients?

Comment: If you attach the debugger and step through the code, you'll see your return statement is the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Everything seems to be good. However, your `redirectToAction` is executing for the first email and comes out of loop.After that control doesn't know how to continue for second record. that's why your email wont be sent to second email. try below code you should be good.

```
for (var index= 0; index< students.Length; index++)
    {
        try
        {
            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(students[index])); 
            message.Subject = "I'm interested in your project";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                       }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox("Your Email address is not valid");
            //ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "popup", "alert('Your Email address is not valid');", true);
        }
    }

     return RedirectToAction("Sent");
```

Answer (score 0):

`return RedirectToAction("Sent");` is the culprit.

This will stop your code after the first email. Don't return from your method until they've *all* been sent:

```
using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
{
  for (int h = 0; h < students.Length; h++)
  {
    var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";

    var message = new MailMessage();
    message.To.Add(new MailAddress(students[h])); 
    message.Subject = "I'm interested in your project";
    message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;

    smtp.Send(message);
  }
}
return RedirectToAction("Sent");
```

N.B. I also removed the redundant try/catch (don't use it if you're not going to log the exception (although you should do that globally anyway), suppressing unexpected errors is an anti-pattern) and reduced the number of times you unnecessarily instantiate a brand new SmtpClient - it's fine to use the same one each time. Also, if you're going to `await` the async email call, there's no point using it - just use the regular Send instead.

Comment: Try/catch in this case wasn't redundant - it served the purpose of ensuring that any one email failing to send didn't prevent the rest from getting delivered. Though agreed, some sort of logging mechanism is definitely needed.

Comment: It was redundant in the sense it did nothing except suppress a legitimate error. I see you might not want it to fail all of them if one errors but what I meant was you need to do something, like logging. Anyway...did the rest of the answer help? If so please remember to mark it as accepted and/or upvote - thanks

Comment: You're addressing the wrong person. I'm just a 3rd party pointing out that it wasn't redundant.

Comment: @mason apologies I missed that, typing on small screen is my feeble excuse

Answer (score 0):

You are returning SENT from inside your loop, so it does the first item then exits.

Comment: By the way, this looks like an ideal candidate for a Parallel.ForEach when you come to optimising.